# nats: no response from stream

Tags: go, nats.io, nats-streaming-server

have error with nats-server -js
when i want publish msg with golang in nats-server -js, i have error like this: **nats: no response from stream**
i want publish video to nats-server -js
this is my pub file:

```
    nc, _ := nats.Connect(nats.DefaultURL)

js, _ := nc.JetStream()

webcam, _ := gocv.VideoCaptureDevice(0)
img := gocv.NewMat()
defer img.Close()
for {
    webcam.Read(&img)
    _, err := js.Publish("ORDERS", img.ToBytes())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?
Thanks in advance for your replys.

Comment: What was the solution. I get the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is ,that you forgot to Add a `stream` .Your nats server is connectable at `4222` (default).But you have to Add a stream to publish and get the data, here is the code in go

```
_, err = js.AddStream(&nats.StreamConfig{
        Name:     "orders",
        Subjects: []string{"ORDERS.*"},
    })
```

See documentation for [more](https://github.com/nats-io/nats.go#jetstream-basic-usage)

Comment: Does the case matter? "order" vs. "ORDER"?

Comment: documentation link has changed to: https://github.com/nats-io/nats.go#basic-usage-1

Answer (score 2):

I think you need specify child subject in publish function (ORDERS.*)
Example: ORDERS.category, ORDERS.abc,.... (NOT: ORDERS)

This is my example with NATS STREAMING JS Pub/Sub Message:

[image]

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/test/global"
    "github.com/nats-io/nats.go"
)

func main() {
    nc, err := nats.Connect(global.GetURL())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    js, err := nc.JetStream()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    _, err = js.Publish("ORDERS.abc", []byte("abc"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tu, can you fix the image link description?

Comment: Please see image link description in link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oISklRGtMrca8Uw61lVvcIPnhdjyY8v6/view?usp=sharing